# How to open notepad in c# by button

Tags: c#, notepad

I am new to programming and stuck on a little thing. I have a button on my Windows application and I want to open Notepad when I click the button. I used all the available codes from internet starting from `process.start()` to even `envirnoment.path` but the button doesn't show the Notepad. Here is what I have already tried.

```
private void btnNotepad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string notepadPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86), "notepad.exe");
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(notepadPath);
}
```

Or simply:

```
system.diagnostics.process.start(@"notepad.exe");
```

Also did this:

```
string theData = txtbxRepeat.Text;
FileStream aFile = new FileStream("myTextFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFile);
txtbxRepeat.Text = theData;
sw.WriteLine(theData);
sw.Close();
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: The last proposal has nothing to do with notepad, it opens or creates a text file and write contents into it. The first looks ok (at first glance!), what's the issue ?

Answer (score -1):

You are heading in the correct direction with the first and 2nd code snippet. However, you need to specify the full path to the notepad++ exe.

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), "Notepad++", @"notepad++.exe"));
    }
```

However, keep in mind the user may have installed notepad++ in a different directory (for example they don't have an x86 directory).

UPDATED: updated to include environment paths rather than hard-coded path.